# Share session between Next and React apps

Tags: reactjs, next.js, keycloak, next-auth

I have a Next application protected with Keycloak through NextAuth, and I have another React application also with the same Keycloak protected with the official keycloak libraries (keycloak-js and react-keycloak/web), both applications live in the same subdomain.

When I log in to Next and then switch to the React app, the user stays logged in as the Keycloak cookies exist, however the other way around, when I log in to React and then switch to Next, it's not recognized the session, I understand that it is because NextAuth has its own cookie and ignores those of Keycloak, my question is:

Is there a way for NextAuth to recognize Keycloak cookies so as not to lose the user's session between applications?

Or what other solution comes to your mind to propagate the session?

Answer (score 0):

You are right about your analysis, your Next application has its own cookie to store tokens. Those tokens should not be available for the React application as those cookies should be in HTTP Only mode.

NextAuth uses OAuth 2.0 if you use the [Keycloak Provider](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/keycloak). If the React application uses an OAuth flow as well, you can make a silent login with OpenID Connect. This is the same authorization code flow your application do when you ask the user to authenticate but with a prompt to none.

Here are the [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) specs for the authentication request. You can also have a look at this [post about the OIDC prompts](https://www.cerberauth.com/openid-connect-prompts#heading-none-prompt) I have written some time ago for more examples.